# How can i make 2d array rows swap in java without using loop?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying rows swap with use this method but i cant do.can anyone help me for this? i need make this without using loops and in one method.

```
     public static void swapRows(double[][] dblMatrix, int i, int j) {
    int temp = dblMatrix[0].length;
    for (int col=0; col<temp; col++){
      swap(dblMatrix, i, col, j, col);
      System.out.printf("%.1f",dblMatrix[i][j]);
    }
}
  public static void swap(double[][] dblMatrix, int i0, int j0, int i1, int j1) {
        double temp1 = dblMatrix[i0][j0];
        dblMatrix[i0][j0] = dblMatrix[i1][j1];
        dblMatrix[i1][j1] = temp1;
      }
```

Comment: please share your effort?

Comment: Please show us your code you got so far.

Comment: Add your code in the question. Don't give us a picture we can't work wih :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should add code in the question itself

Comment: I don't see any use making this without loops and just using the stack to LOOP through by calling the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very useful but its relativly easy to do it without loops, but you will have to pass all variables as parameters to the next function call. Also notice that without the return statement the stack would grow infinitly large.

Your second swap function is also very useless as you don't need a seperate function just to swap some values.

```
public void swapRows(double[][] matrix, int row1, int row2, int start, int end) {
      double d = matrix[row1][start];
      matrix[row1][start] = matrix[row2][start];
      matrix[row2][start] = d;
      start++;
      if(start==end) {
          return;
      }
      swapRows(matrix, row1, row2, start, end);
  }
```